# Is it a good idea to join SIGGRAPH without a degree?

Tags: computer-science, undergraduate, education

I needed to cancel my studies in the last semester due to finances. I mod computer games, love 3D-modelling, did a little bit in graphics-programming. I absolutely love the field. I am currently in a retraining as an IT specialist for application development, but is that enough to join [SIGGRAPH](https://www.siggraph.org/)?

I want to know, if I am just being too enthusiastic. I found SIGGRAPH in 2013 and have followed it since and watched basically every video from them on YouTube. Some of the content I have no problem following. The advanced level goes over my head. I want to get my foot in the industry, I want to connect with others. I want to visit the conference ... but maybe I should keep my head down.

Could somebody please give me an advice or an opinion?

Comment: What's siggraph?

Comment: SIGGRAPH is a special interest group for graphics and interactive techniques: https://www.siggraph.org/ belonging to the Association for computing machinery

Comment: I have been to Siggraph several times and I would definitely recommend you going. No one will look down on you that you are not a PhD student or whatever, there are many people from industry, they are probably in majority. Unfortunately, this year it is virtual again as in 2020 and it sucked in my opinion, but hey the cost to entry is way lower.

Comment: Thanks @tom for your reply. In the videos and streams I saw I got the feeling that it is a community and people are really dedicated to the field of computer graphics and I want to connect to people who have the same passion, I want to learn more and build upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Students get a special rate when they join ACM and/or its SIGs (special interest groups). You get the Communications as part ACM membership. You can also join any of several special interest groups such as SIGGRAPH. There is some cost for that even for students. But you get their publications, either electronically (cheap) or in printed form (less cheap). There are, I think, special prices for conference attendance at the annual conference for members.

The special deals don't apply to non-students, of course. Most academics in CS are likely to be ACM members and those interested in graphics are likely SIGGRAPH members.

It probably isn't essential to do this, depending on how connected you want to be to that community over time. But the publications are interesting if you are interested in the topic, and the conference(s) are great for career building. SIGGraph is a huge event.

Some universities, however, have local "chapters" of ACM and they may have additional local activities for members.

ACM and SIG members can also subscribe to the ACM digital library which gives you access to just about everything ACM has published since some early date (and they are digitizing the old stuff). But a local university library can probably get you access to that as well, though they might require some affiliation with the university.

Comment: It is a good anser but I will not go to university again. I am doing a shortened apprenticeship now (I was able to shorten it because of my unfinished computer-science-studies). And I am from germany.